# White screen when load to new page

Tags: jquery-mobile, screen

Hi i am new for jquery mobile 1.4.2. After i compile my application to apk and I also install to my phone which is android 4.3 . Everything is run quite smooth. But when i install to other phone which is android 4.2.Then the problem cum. When  load to other page. The screen will keep white screen while loading to new screen.

I try below solution

```
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function () {

    $.mobile.buttonMarkup.hoverDelay = 0;
    $.mobile.defaultPageTransition = 'none';
    $.mobile.defaultDialogTransition = 'none';
//    $.mobile.page.prototype.options.domCache = true;
    $.mobile.defaultHomeScroll = 0.


});
```

Change the meta

```
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1  user-scalable=no maximum-scale=1"" >
```

But i still having this issue . Any solution to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

To avoid ***white screen*** add following css

```
.ui-mobile, .ui-mobile body{
  background:url('bg_screen.png') no-repeat left top;
}
```

**OR**

Add *color* as you want

```
.ui-mobile, .ui-mobile body{
  background:#999;
}
```

Comment: possible to improve the speed of loading page? seem like nt user friendly every time user wait the loading screen to load the new page

Comment: its depend on how to load data in your app. you can load data on pagecreate OR pageinit event.

Comment: http://www.gajotres.net/building-a-native-mobile-app-with-phonegap-and-jquery-mobile-1-4/